# mobile device managment

Tags: mobile

My requirement is i need to propose Mobile Device management(MDM) tool to the customer which will have all required features(Device Registration,Permissions to the device, Push mobile apps to the device etc )

FYI : The MDM tool should support **IPHONE**, **ANDROID**, **BlACKBERRY**, **SYMBIAN** & **WINDOWSPHONE**

Is there any MDM tool in the market which i can download and install freely.

Thanks
RVS

Comment: this is not possible - every phone has it's own market place which handles apps

Answer (score 1):

Free MDM solutions may exist : http://www.spiceworks.com/free-mobile-device-management-mdm-software/
Yet I am not sure that this may be a viable solution for your Clients.

For a non-exhaustive list of MDM solution providers:  http://www.enterpriseios.com/wiki/Comparison_MDM_Providers

**Note** : MobileIron also offers an On-Premise solution where the Virtual Smartphone Platform and eventual Integrated Sentries are installed in the client's network infrastructure (note : on-premise). Also, if the client does opt for the Connected Cloud solution, the VSP only is hosted on the Cloud.

In other words, there is the possibility to implement a Standalone Sentry (which can NOT be hosted on the Cloud) in the client's infrastructure to encrypt all data outgoing to the VSP, this is known as a Hybrid solution. The possibility of implementing a Standalone Sentry hosted on the Cloud is 'scheduled' for late 2014.

Answer (score 0):

I think we have tools like **ZENPRISE** which supports all the major Device vendors.

It seems the above tool is bit costlier, they are charging $35 per user.

we have another solutions like **MAAS360** & **MOBILEIRON** but they are Cloud based (all employee details will be stored remotely). Most of the customers prefer local installation as they do not want disclose their company information.

My Question is, are there any tools like **zenprise** which are much freely/cheaper than this tool ?

Thanks
RVS

Answer (score 0):

I was searching through the web, looking for free MDM solutions to compile a list. I landed on this page and it helped me with sorting out Spiceworks, so I thought it would be good to do my bit by submitting the list that I compiled.

There are 5 free MDM software that I was able to find out that actually provide free service, although some have restricted functionality.

1. [Miradore](https://www.miradore.com/miradore-online-for-mobile-device-management/)
2. [Spiceworks](https://spiceworks.com/)
3. [Desktop Central](https://www.manageengine.com/products/desktop-central/)
4. [Relution](https://www.relution.io/en/)
5. [AppTec EMM](https://www.apptec360.com/solutions/mobile-device-management/)

Well, I couldn't write about them all here; already took a lot of time to compile and write about the features made available for free. **Here is a link where I go into much greater detail.: [5 Free Mobile Device Management Software](http://listoffreeware.com/free-mobile-device-management-software/)**